# Spring Boot JPA Hibernate JVM heap is not released

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

The following is a simplification of a more complicated setup. I describe this simple case to show the effect.

I start Spring Boot and call a method. In this method all the contents of a MySQL database table is read via

```
Iterable<myPojo> myPojos = myPojoRepository.findAll();
```

Afterwards I leave this method.

After finishing this method I get the message

```
Started Application in 70.893 seconds (JVM running for 72.899)
```

So Spring Boot is idling afterwards.

But still the memory is not released.

**How can I avoid that the JVM Heap is not released after the application is idling?**

This is the result of VisualJM after the application is idling:

```
char[]                        1.080.623.712 (21.0%)  24.040.578 (23.4%)
byte[]                        1.034.070.352 (20.1%)  17.280.824 (16.8%)
java.lang.String                768.935.872 (14.9%)  24.029.246 (23.4%)
java.lang.Object[]              556.181.104 (10.8%)   5.320.276 (5.1%)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.MutableEntityEntry
                                 231.287.232 (4.5%)   2.628.264 (2.5%)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey
                                 224.752.040 (4.3%)   5.618.801 (5.4%)
byte[][]                         212.407.904 (4.1%)   3.318.832 (3.2%)
hello.web.model.MyPojo           185.852.968 (3.6%)   3.318.803 (3.2%)
java.util.HashMap$Node           145.238.976 (2.8%)   3.025.812 (2.9%)
com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow      132.752.120 (2.5%)   3.318.803 (3.2%)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext$ManagedEntityImpl
                                 126.156.720 (2.4%)   2.628.265 (2.5%)
hello.web.model.MyPojoCompoundKey
                                 120.376.680 (2.3%)   3.009.417 (2.9%)
java.util.HashMap$Node[]         108.307.328 (2.1%)      16.558 (0.0%)
java.lang.Float                   79.651.320 (1.5%)   3.318.805 (3.2%)
int[]                             41.885.056 (0.8%)      54.511 (0.0%)
java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry     15.519.616 (0.3%)     242.494 (0.2%)
java.io.File                      11.323.392 (0.2%)     235.904 (0.2%)
org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSnapshot
                                  10.550.400 (0.2%)     219.800 (0.2%)
java.lang.String[]                 8.018.808 (0.1%)      52.031 (0.0%)
java.lang.reflect.Method           6.015.040 (0.1%)      37.594 (0.0%)
java.io.File[]                     2.283.528 (0.0%)      16.746 (0.0%)
```

My effective-pom.xml shows that `hibernate 5.0.9.Final` is used.
The table `my_pojo` contains 3.3 million entries.

MyPojoRepository:

```
package hello.web.model;

import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface MyPojoRepository
        extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyPojo, Long>, 
                QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyPojo> {

    List<MyPojo> findAll(Predicate predicate);    
}
```

MyPojo:
    package hello.web.model;

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanComparator;
import org.apache.commons.collections.comparators.ComparatorChain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@IdClass(MyPojoCompoundKey.class)
public class MyPojo implements Serializable, Comparable<MyPojo> {
    public MyPojo() {    }

    @Id
    private String myId1;
    @Id
    private String myId2;
    @Id
    private String myId3;
    private Float myId4;
    private String myId5;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyPojo o) {
        return this.getMyId3().compareTo(o.getMyId3());
    }
    protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
        return other instanceof MyPojo;
    }
    public static void sortByMyId1MyId3(List<MyPojo> myPojos) {
        ComparatorChain chain = new ComparatorChain(Arrays.asList(
                new BeanComparator("myId1"),
                new BeanComparator("myId3")
        ));
        Collections.sort(myPojos, chain);
    }
}
```

myId1-3 and myId5 have a length of 10 characters in avarage.

So again:
**How can I avoid that the JVM Heap is not released after the application is idling?**

Comment: I guess the question is about how Garbage Collection works. The idea is that you should not care about the memory as long it is not leaking. It should not be your problem but JVM problem.

Comment: The garbage collector has several options to tinker with. You can request that he kicks in and starts a collection using `System.gc()` from your application.

Comment: Calling gc as @JChrist mentioned is not a good idea in my opinion. You are not going to get deterministic behavior.

Comment: so in my real setup, the main memory gets used up, afterwards the swap memory. Please be assured, that my question is aiming to the frameworks used. Java, JVM and garbage collection work properly here.

Comment: I made a test without QueryDsl. The performance (almost 30 seconds faster) as well as the memory footprint (2.2 GByte vs 4.1 GByte according to VisualVM) are much better. As long as nobody knows the parameter of QueryDsl that is responsible for the caching, I will skip QueryDsl for memory sensitive tasks.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this issue?